# Upgrade decision on Amazon RDS with respect to EBS and ReadOnly replicas

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

At present we use a reserved db.m1.large RDS instance which is usually running at between 50% and 80%. Most interaction to it is from EC2 instances within the same region, either via java code or through a web server.

We are contemplating upgrading to db.m3.large/xlarge and are wondering about two issues. Firstly, is the communication above classified as EBS, thus would we benefit from an EBS optimised instance? Secondly, after upgrading to db.m3.*, would it make sense to keep the existing subscription and have a readonly replica on db.m1.large? Guessing that it would make the readonly access faster (if it was sent to the read replica) and also be better for CPU usage or would all this be offset by the replication process.

Note that the read replica being a few seconds behind the main DB is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- As you are using RDS, you do not have access to the underlying instances or volumes, so you would not be to choose if it is "EBS Optimized" or not. "EBS Optmized" means a separate network interface for storage traffic, so it will not concur with application traffic. Currently in RDS, db.m3.large are not EBS Optimized and db.m3.xlarge are, in a 500 Mbps network.

2- This is quite dependent to your context, but if you offload most of your reads to a read replica, you may even not need to upgrade the master at all. But it would not make sense to "keep the existing subscription". As you pay for what you use, you can just delete the old instance and spin a new read replica from the new master.

Comment: 1. Does EBS Optimized benefit my setup or is db.m3.xlarge just twice as big as db.m3.large? 2. Still have more than a year on reserved db.m1.large Heavy Utilitization, so was planning to have a (new) read replica on it.

Comment: 1. Yes, because you'll have a dedicated connection to EBS. 2. Reservations are not tied to specific instances, so if the new replica is of the same size and AZ, your reservation will match.

Comment: Are you saying that I could use my db.m1.large reservation for a new db.m3.large provided I delete the old instance?

Comment: Not at all, what i am saying is that if you have one reservation for a db.m1.large, it is not tied to that one specific rds database instance. You can delete the old and start the new one (as a replica), with the same instance type, and your reservations should still match.